# ExtJs 3.2.1 Applying CSS margins to a combo box

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs3

I'm having an issue in an old version of ExtJs where if I add a css margin to a button then it looks like this:

[image: Two Combo boxes and a button]

It normally looks like this:

[image: Combo boxes working fine.]

The only difference is this line of code:

```
style : 'marginRight:16px;',
```

Where am I going wrong or is there an alternative to doing it this way?

Comment: does the button and the combobox share a common class?

Comment: I removed any css that would act on both objects and got the same behaviour. Tested in chrome 42.0.2311.152 m and IE11.

Comment: @Shane Can you add fiddle demo pls. ?

Comment: use padding left for the button , instead of marginRight and check

Comment: None of the shown elements actually has a width of 40px, so I wonder what your style gets applied to?

Comment: Sorry I took out the width when I did the screenshot just to see if it would make a difference.

PaddingLeft didn't work as it applies to the text in the button not the button itself.

Comment: Also I cant get a fiddle to run on the older versions of Extjs 3.x

Answer (score 0):

You can add CSS class containing the margin to the button with the cls config or via addClass method like so:

```
yourButton.addClass( 'marginRight16' );
```

and your CSS:

```
marginRight16 {
    margin-right:16px;
}
```